# How to enable CORS in softlayer object storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I am using the Softlayer object storage and accessing my objects in the S3 bucket using SDK API from my Node.js application deployed on IBM Bluemix. I am able to insert the objects in the bucket but while accessing the object using SDK API I am getting the CORS error as below:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/<my bucket-name>/<my object-name>. No. 'Access Control-......Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested source. Origin 'http://localhost:6009' is therefore not allowed.`

In AWS S3, we can configure the properties at the bucket level and we can explicitly enable CORS but then I don't see any such option in Softlayer.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the guides at https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-operations.html

This is the official documentation for the Cloud Object Storage (S3) offering.

Answer (score 0):

Object Storage uses standard S3 API and it seems you has chosen Object Storage S3 API so that you can use [AWS SDK (php sdk in my case)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putbucketcors) to enable CORS and another policies at the bucket level.

That's how I did it:

```
$s3Client->putBucketCors([
    'Bucket' => 'your-object-storage-bucket-name',
    'CORSConfiguration' => [
        'CORSRules' => [
            [
                'AllowedHeaders' => ['*'],
                'AllowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
                'AllowedOrigins' => ['*'],
            ]
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Regarding IBM Softlayer: I reported this issue about 3 month ago and I asked for code samples but they didnt neither solve my problem nor provide a concrete reference, that's a pitty because the operator recommended I have to post this issue in stackoverflow and wait for IBM developers answers since they cant to communicate to them, so docs is poor and customer support is disappointing.

I hope this info help you.