# How to enable CORS in SoftLayer object storage?

Tags: javascript, cdn, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

Trying to get icons from object storage and getting;

`Access to Font at 'http://****.http.dal05.cdn.softlayer.net/**********' from origin 'http://localhost:3034' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3034' is therefore not allowed access.`

I guess it should be fixed on SO side but have no idea where to look?

Comment: ok, I saw only one 'swift' in tag list so just picked it up.

Answer (score 0):

SL Object Storage only support CORS on containers and not individual objects. The following headers should be supported:

X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Origins to be allowed to make Cross Origin Requests, space separated.

X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Max-Age
Max age for the Origin to hold the preflight results.

X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Regards

Comment: and how should I allowed it in the object storage? that the question, I've just asked tech.support and they don't know

Answer (score 0):

Object Storage also uses standard S3 API, [this answer show you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46306107/1911787) how to do that using Object Storage S3 API.